# Importing Python file from PostgreSQL stored procedure

Tags: python, postgresql, stored-procedures

It is possible to have Python code in a PostgreSQL stored procedure. For example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION someProc()
RETURNS void AS $$
    # Some Python3 code...
$$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;
```

But how can I include a python file from this code?

The current directory of Python running in PostgreSQL is this:

```
>>> os.getcwd()
... /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main
```

I tryied the following, which worked:

```
CREATE FUNCTION someProc()
RETURNS void AS $$
    import sys
    sys.path.append("/dir/to/file")
    from python_file import pythonFunction
    # More Python code
$$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;
```

This doesn't seem very good for many obvious reasons. Is there a better way to import a python file, or just calling a python function from a python file?

**Edit:** There isn't any specific PostgreSQL method to import a file. But  the best way is in the correct answer bellow, which resembles my original solution but it is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is no different to dynamically loading Python code from a file in standalone Python:

- [How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67631/398670)

PL/Python3 (untrusted) is just the cpython interpreter running embedded in a PostgreSQL backend process as the same operating system user PostgreSQL its self runs as. With a very few differences - like thread safety - it's just Python.

Comment: Thank you, although I wouldn't really consider this a duplicate question because I am coming for a specific PostgreSQL stored procedure method to find that there is none, and the solution is actually a more general Python one. But again, thank you!

Comment: Absolutely - it's helpful to ask, and now this question will point people at the more general answer when they come looking for PL/PgSQL. If I thought it was 100% duplicate I would've just closed it as a dup without posting an answer too.

Comment: Ah ok, I thought this question would get deleted or something. Sorry for the confusion, and again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this from the documentation?

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/plpython.html

Comment: Well, yes I have looked into the documentation, but didn't find a solution there.

Comment: Where in the plpython docs does it refer to reading external files to load Python code? I don't think you fully read the question.